# iOS - Update UI on variable value changed

Tags: ios, variables, listener

I have a int variable called recordingStatus. 
I would like to "listen" to this recording status and update my label based on the status of this variable.

```
int recordingStatus;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *recordingStatusText;
```

The reason I have to do so is that recordingStatus is being changed in my C code (also in the same file) and the C code doesn't have access to the UI elements (as far as I know).

What's the most elegant way to do this in iOS?

C Code Core Audio Callback

```
static OSStatus rioRecordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                              UInt32 inBusNumber,
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {

// want to access recordingStatus in here, am I able to do it without passsing it in via inRefCon?
}
```

Thanks.

Pier.

Comment: I eventually found the solution I required here, for audio rendering c code where time is critical it was recommended to do a poll on the variable in question using timer. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151772/triggering-ui-code-from-audio-unit-render-proc-on-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can approach this. As Rickay noted, you can make it a property and just override the setters to set the value of your label as well.

The other approach is to use KVO to monitor `recordingStatus` (it will still need to have a property). If you're looking for a super awesome way to use KVO, check out [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa). This type of observe-react pattern is known as *reactive programming*.

Comment: Thanks sudo rm -rf .. I'll check out KVO when I have the time :) The simpler method suffices for now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer anyways as I've learnt something from it :)

Answer (score 1):

Make `recordingStatus` a property of your object. Then you can override the setter method and in that method perform whatever UI updates you need to. This way, the C code doesn't need to worry about the UI, and the Objective-C code can handle Objective-C UI updates.

Comment: Thanks.. how do I make recordingStatus visible to my C code then? I've done this - @synthesize recordingStatus , followed by - (void) setRecordingStatus:(int)recordingStatus {
    recordingStatusText.text = @"Just testing!";
}

Comment: You can access the object's property as you would any other. If you are talking about accessing `self` inside of a C function, you will need to pass a reference to the instance whose property you would like to change.

Answer (score -1):

with reference to another thread [Triggering UI code from Audio Unit Render Proc on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151772/triggering-ui-code-from-audio-unit-render-proc-on-ios)

I put recordingStatus into a struct that is passed into the audio callback, and a main loop polls the value at an average refresh rate of 60hz , hence (1/60 == 0.02 sec).

```
- (void) initTimer
{
self.UIUpdateTimer =
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02
                                 target:self selector:@selector(pollValues:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
}

- (void) pollValues:(NSTimer *)paramTimer
{
if (rio.recordingStatus==1)
    recordingStatusLabel.text = @"test!";
}
```